# What are the elements of group $\left(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/3\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]\right)^{\times}/\{\pm1\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

What are the elements of group $\left(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/3\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]\right)^{\times}/\{\pm1\}$ (if $R$ is a ring then, $R^{\times}$ is the group of units of $R$)?

I know that the elements of  $\left(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/3\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]\right)^{\times}$ in the form of tuples are $(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)$ where $(a,b)$ denotes $a+b\sqrt{-3}+3\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. I am not entirely sure how the coset operation of $\{\pm1\}$ works on the group of units here. I understand that $(1,0), (2,0)$ would be absorbed by $\{\pm1\}$ but what about the other elements as it is possible to have only two more elements? What am I missing here?

Is it correct that $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ are equivalent under the coset operation of $\{\pm1\}$ and same for $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$?

Comment: First, I think that your description is not complete, since if $(a,b)$ is a unit then so is $(-a,-b)$ (and certainly so is $(a,-b)$ as well). Moreover, the group operation here is multiplicative. Therefore when taking quotient by $\{\pm1\}$, you are just identifying all tuples $(a,b)$ with their opposite tuples $(-a,-b)$.

Comment: @Suzet I think $(-a,-b)$ and $(a,-b)$ are already covered by the coset operation of $3\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Isn't it? So, I just mentioned the equivalence classes.

Comment: Or shall I list out the tuples as $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(-1,0)$, $(-1, 1)$ and $(-1,-1)$?

Comment: My apologies, you are right! Your description may be complete then (although I have not done the computations to check by myself). As you suggest, if you replace the $2$'s by $-1$'s, it is easier to see the action of $\{\pm 1\}$ as I described in my first comment. For instance, in the quotient, the tuples $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$ will be identified.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(3)^\times =\{ s (1+a \sqrt{-3}+(3)),a\in \{0,1,2\}, s=\pm 1\}$.